# Execution Timeout Expired after inserting into database and then using EF Core to update database with completion

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

Note: This runs without any issues on my local computer, but when I push it up to our Azure instance I see the TimeoutExpired

I'm running into a weird issue where we are inserting records into the database. The file I'm working on has 103k inserts. The actual inserts to the database are completed successfully. When it goes to update my database table via EF Core that the import has been successful I see this error:

```
Error: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__180_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.<ExecuteAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.<ExecuteAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.<ExecuteAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsync>d__7`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<SaveChangesAsync>d__81.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<SaveChangesAsync>d__79.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.<SaveChangesAsync>d__53.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at PTI.BI.API.ExcelImporter.DAL.Repositories.BaseRepository.<SaveChangesAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at PTI.BI.API.ExcelImporter.DAL.Repositories.ImportRepository.<UpdateImportGenerateScript>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at PTI.BI.API.ExcelImporter.BLL.Service.ImportService.<UpdateImportGenerateScript>d__31.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at PTI.BI.API.ExcelImporter.BLL.Service.ImportService.<ProcessImport>d__47.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
```

Here is the code that is doing the updates to my database, one at a time (for error checking). This code is working fine.

```
            using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    sqlTransaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction();

                    // #### Pre populate items (generate delete statement)
                    trackingInfo.FileDetail = UpdateImportMetricStatus(trackingInfo.FileDetail, ImportMetricStatus.PrepopulateScript);
                    trackingInfo = await PrepopulateApplyScript(trackingInfo).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    if (trackingInfo.IsSuccessful == false)
                    {
                        return trackingInfo;
                    }

                    // apply the delete records sql script if found.
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(trackingInfo.DeleteRecordsSqlScript.ToString()) == false)
                    {
                        trackingInfo.FileDetail = UpdateImportMetricStatus(trackingInfo.FileDetail, ImportMetricStatus.GenerateDeleteSqlScript);

                        errorSqlScript = trackingInfo.DeleteRecordsSqlScript.ToString();

                        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(trackingInfo.DeleteRecordsSqlScript.ToString(), sqlConnection, sqlTransaction))
                        {
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                        }

                        // append delete statement to the main SQL script
                        trackingInfo.SqlScript.AppendLine(trackingInfo.DeleteRecordsSqlScript.ToString());
                    }

                    // #### Create table script IF we are creating a new table
                    if (trackingInfo.FileDetail.DestinationDetail.CreateNewTable == true && trackingInfo.FileDetail.DestinationDetail.UseExistingTable == false)
                    {
                        trackingInfo = await CreateTableScript(trackingInfo).ConfigureAwait(false);

                        if (trackingInfo.IsSuccessful == false)
                        {
                            return trackingInfo;
                        }

                        // apply the create table sql script if found.
                        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(trackingInfo.CreateTableSqlScript.ToString()) == false)
                        {
                            trackingInfo.FileDetail = UpdateImportMetricStatus(trackingInfo.FileDetail, ImportMetricStatus.GenerateCreateTableScript);

                            errorSqlScript = trackingInfo.CreateTableSqlScript.ToString();

                            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(trackingInfo.CreateTableSqlScript.ToString(), sqlConnection, sqlTransaction))
                            {
                                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                            }

                            // append delete statement to the main SQL script
                            trackingInfo.SqlScript.AppendLine(trackingInfo.CreateTableSqlScript.ToString());
                        }
                    }

                    // ### Insert table scripts
                    trackingInfo.FileDetail = UpdateImportMetricStatus(trackingInfo.FileDetail, ImportMetricStatus.GenerateInsertScripts);
                    trackingInfo = await GenerateInsertTableScript(trackingInfo).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    // apply the create table sql script if found.
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(trackingInfo.InsertSqlScript.ToString()) == false)
                    {
                        trackingInfo.FileDetail = UpdateImportMetricStatus(trackingInfo.FileDetail, ImportMetricStatus.PopulatingInsertScripts);

                        foreach (var item in trackingInfo.InsertSqlScript)
                        {
                            errorSqlScript = item;

                            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(item, sqlConnection, sqlTransaction))
                            {
                                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                            }

                            currentRowLine++;

                            // append insert statements to the main script...
                            trackingInfo.SqlScript.AppendLine(item).AppendLine();
                        }
                    }

                    if (trackingInfo.IsSuccessful == false)
                    {
                        return trackingInfo;
                    }

                    if (trackingInfo.IsSuccessful == true)
                    {
                        sqlTransaction.Commit();
                        return trackingInfo;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return trackingInfo;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    sqlTransaction.Rollback();

                    trackingInfo.IsSuccessful = false;
                    trackingInfo.ImportMetricUpdateError = new ImportMetricUpdateErrorDTO(trackingInfo.ImportMetricId)
                    {
                        ErrorLineNbr = currentRowLine + 1, // add one to match up with the excel file
                        ErrorMessage = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}", ex.Message),
                        ErrorSQL = errorSqlScript,
                        RowsProcessed = currentRowLine
                    };

                    await LogImporterError(trackingInfo.FileDetail, ex.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    return trackingInfo;
                }
            }
```

Again, the delete, create, insert statements all work and update my SQL database without any issues.

Then here is where my code fails:

```
        public async Task UpdateImportMetric(ImportMetricUpdateDTO importMetricUpdate)
        {
            if (importMetricUpdate == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(importMetricUpdate));
            }

            var importMetricDbRecord = await ImportContext.ImportMetrics
                                    .Where(x => x.ImportMetricId == importMetricUpdate.ImportMetricId)
                                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (importMetricDbRecord == null)
            {
                throw new RecordNotFoundException("No import metric with id: " + importMetricUpdate.ImportMetricId + " could be found.");
            }

            importMetricDbRecord.ImportStatus = importMetricUpdate.ImportStatus;
            importMetricDbRecord.ImportStatusHistoriesJson = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(importMetricUpdate.ImportStatusHistoriesJson) == true ? importMetricDbRecord.ImportStatusHistoriesJson : importMetricUpdate.ImportStatusHistoriesJson;
            importMetricDbRecord.Ended = importMetricUpdate.Ended;
            importMetricDbRecord.Duration = importMetricUpdate.Duration;
            importMetricDbRecord.RowsProcessed = importMetricUpdate.RowsProcessed;
            importMetricDbRecord.IsSuccessful = importMetricUpdate.IsSuccessful;
            importMetricDbRecord.ErrorLineNbr = importMetricUpdate.ErrorLineNbr;
            importMetricDbRecord.ErrorMessage = importMetricUpdate.ErrorMessage;
            importMetricDbRecord.ErrorSQL = importMetricUpdate.ErrorSQL;
            importMetricDbRecord.ModifiedBy = ImportContext.UserRequestingId;
            importMetricDbRecord.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

            await SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

As you can see the issue appears to be on my SaveChangesAsync().

So I think it is something with EF Core instead of the code to actually insert the statements into the db since that appears to be working.

Also, after starting the Import from the user clicking a button on the MVC page, I am kicking off the Import in Async mode, so the UI responds back and a loading panel will run for the user.

Here is that code:

```
#pragma warning disable CS4014 // Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed
            Task.Run(async ()=> await ProcessImport(submitImportItemsAndProcessImport.ImportDetailId, importMetricId, currentUserId));
#pragma warning restore CS4014 // Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed
```

I'm in a using() on the connection so that should be closed out.

It is almost like something is being left open and therefore EF Core can't continue with the updates after moving away from using SQLCommand.

Any ideas?

Comment: Consider disposing SQLTransaction.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

It appears the script is so large that StringBuilder.ToString(); was causing an Out of Memory exception and thus causing the timeout.

Since the script is so large. We are planning to go to FileStream instead of StringBuilder.

Comment: If you're messing around with sql to insert a bunch of records, I'd consider using `SqlBulkCopy`. Perhaps even dumping all the data to a temp table and processing in a stored proc. While EF Core does batch some similar sql operations together, it (currently) uses parameter binding for passing all values, which limits throughput.